# How to generate 10 unique random numbers from a set of 100 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I'm working on a minesweeper web app and i am trying to generate 10 mines with unique location id's (1-100). I wrote a function to do this, and log the 10 numbers to an array called numbers. But every time I run the program it produces 10 identical numbers from 1-100. Does anyone know what I did wrong? (Update: It worked when I changed the loop from while to do...while but the question now is why did that fix it?)

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var chooseMines = function(num) {
  var temp,bool,numbers = [];
  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    do
    {
        bool = 0;
        temp = Math.floor(100 * Math.random()) + 1;
        for(j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if(numbers[j] === temp)
            {
                bool = 1;
            }
        }
    } while(bool)
    numbers.push(temp);
}
window.confirm(numbers);
return numbers;
};
```

This is my old js:

```
var chooseMines = function(num) {
  var temp,bool = 1,numbers = [];
  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    while(bool)
    {
        bool = 0;
        temp = Math.floor(100 * Math.random) + 1;
        for(j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if(numbers[j] === temp)
            {
                bool = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    numbers.push(temp);
}
window.confirm(numbers);
return numbers;
};
```

Comment: Appear to return array containing `NaN` ? , also `Math.random` not being called ?

Comment: Why are you setting `bool` to `1` and `0` instead of just using `true` and `false`?

Comment: because 1 and 0 are quicker to type, and im not very good at typing

Comment: `Math.random` is a function so it has to be called `Math.random()`

Comment: i just fixed that in the question

Comment: What is the use of the `num` argument?

Comment: After i get this to work, the num argument will be how many numbers the random numbers can come from (I'm making minesweeper with different board sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the updated question**, the reason you continually got the same number is because the first time you run through it you set `bool` to `0`. Then you set `temp` to a random number. All this is fine, until you reach the inner `for` loop. What happens is it skips that for loop since `j = 0`, `numbers.length` is equal to `0`, and `j < numbers.length` is `false`. Which means `bool` is still set to `0` when the `while` loop ends. Which prevents it from ever running again. But the outer `for` loop still runs 9 more times, pushing `temp` (which is already a set number) onto the `numbers` array. Also, you didn't have the parenthesis on `Math.random`.

The updated version works because every time you do the main `for` loop, the code is going to do the code in the `do..while` loop at least once. The first time it doesn't do the inner `for` loop, but the other 9 times `j` is less than `numbers.length` so it works.

Also this code works and prevents you from needing that `bool` variable:

```
var chooseMines = function(num) {
    var num = num || 100;
    var currentNum = 0;
    var mines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        do {
            currentNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * num);
        } while(mines.includes(currentNum))
        mines.push(currentNum);
    }
    return mines;
}
```

You can either set the `num` variable or not. It defaults to 100.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single `while` loop, `Array.prototype.indexOf()`

```js
  var r = function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1)
}

function randArr(num) {
  var res = [];
  while (res.length < num) {
    var rand = r();
    if (res.indexOf(rand) == -1)
      res.push(rand)
    else res[res.indexOf(rand)] = r()
  };
  return res
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) console.log(randArr(10))
```

alternatively, using two `while` loops

```js
var r = function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1)
}

function randArr(num) {
  var res = [];
  while (res.length < num) {
    var rand = r();
    while (res.indexOf(rand) != -1) {
      rand = r();
    }
    res.push(rand);
  };
  return res
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) console.log(randArr(10))
```

Comment: @NullSpark _"Does anyone know what I did wrong? (Update: It worked when I changed the loop from while to do...while but the question now is why did that fix it?)"_ Initial `js` at Question did not call `Math.random()` . Perhaps leave original `js` at Question to compare ?